# Multiple functions in R, argument missing with no default

Tags: r, function

I have some problem with the following code. It states that

```
Error in char_func(phi, kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, r, : argument "kappa" is missing, with no default
```

Where my code is:

```
  f <- function(x,y){
  complex(real = x, imaginary = y)
}
char_func <- function(phi, kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, r, type2){
  a = kappa*theta
  if(type2 == 1){
    u = 1/2
    b = kappa - sigma * cor}
  else{
    u = -1/2
    b = kappa + theta}
  x = log(s)
  m <- sqrt((b-cor*sigma*
                      (f(0,1))*phi)^2-sigma^2*(2*phi*u*(f(0,1))-phi^2))
  g <- (b-cor * sigma * phi * (f(0,1))-m)/
      (b- cor * sigma * phi * (f(0,1)) + m)
  C <- r * (f(0,1)) * phi * tau + a/sigma^2 *((b-cor*sigma*(f(0,1))*phi-m)*
                          tau-2*log((1-g*exp(-m*tau))/(1-g)))
  D <- ((b-cor*sigma*phi*(f(0,1))-m)*(1-exp(-m*tau)))/(sigma^2*(1-g*exp(-m*tau)))
  f <- exp(C+D*cur_var+(f(0,1))*phi*x)
  
  return(f)
}

integrand <- function(phi, kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, X, r, type2){
  Ff <- char_func(phi, kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, r, type2)
  integ <- (Re((exp(-(f(0,1))*phi*log(X))*Ff)/((f(0,1))*phi)))
  
  return(integ)
}

P <- function(kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, X, r, type2){
  P = 1/2+1/pi * integrate(integrand, 0, Inf)
  
  return(P)
}

Price <- function(kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, X, r){
  P_1 <- P(kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, X, r, 0)
  P_2 <- P(kappa, theta, sigma, cor, cur_var, tau, s, X, r, 1)
  price <- s*P_1 - exp(-r*tau)*X*P_2
  
  return(price)
}



Price(kappa = 2, theta = 0.02, sigma = 0.3, cor = -0.5, cur_var = 0.01, 
      tau = 0.5, s = 100, X = 80, r = 0)

P_1 <- P(2, 0.02, 0.3, -0.5, 0.01, 0.5, 100, 80, 0, 0)
```

I have tried looking through the functions to see why it messes up, however, I have not found the problem. The problem seems like it comes from my first function; char_func. As you can see in my code, however, I have stated what kappa should be.
Hope you can help with the problem! Thank you!

Comment: In your `p` function, you are calling `integrate(integrand, 0, Inf)` but you aren't actually passing all the variables to your `integrand` function. All those parameters are missing. Try `integrate(integrand, 0, Inf, kappa=kappa, theta=theta, sigma=sigma, cor=cor, cur_val=cur_var, tau=tau, s=s, X=X, r=r, type2=type2)`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the kappa missing problem. But it created a new problem with 
"Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (cur_val = 0.01)". Do I need to paste the code into other parts?

Comment: It was a type. Should have been `cur_var = cur_var`, not `cur_val=cur_var`

Comment: Thanks, did not actually see that. My bad!
I am stilling having some problems though, so I am gonna ask another question if it is alright. It now states that
"Error in 1/pi * integrate(integrand, 0, Inf, kappa = kappa, theta = theta,  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"